# mysql summation with condition on individual rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 fields (of relevance to the question). One field is numeric, the other two have text-based content. I want to get the sum of the numeric field as follows:

1. Group by field A
2. If Field B is equal to X, then add
3. If Field B is equal to Y, then subtract

   ABC, X, 25
   ABC, X, 15
   ABC, Y, 10
   DEF, X, 20
   DEF, Y, 5

The above data would return:

```
ABC, 30
DEF, 15
```

My query, ideally, would produce the equivalent of the following the following:

```
SELECT fieldA, SUM(fieldC) AS sum1 FROM my_table WHERE fieldB = 'X' GROUP BY fieldA
SELECT fieldA, SUM(fieldC) AS sum2 FROM my_table WHERE fieldB = 'Y' GROUP BY fieldA

RESULT = sum1 - sum2
```

How can I do this in a single query?

Comment: Use `CASE` and if the field is `Y` then multiply `FieldB` by `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
  FieldA,
  SUM(CASE WHEN FieldB = 'X' THEN FieldC ELSE -FieldC END) AS Result
FROM my_table
GROUP BY FieldA
```